# error in objects source with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my first time to make an object in JS.

Can someone help me understand why the sourve did not work?

**this is the full source:**

```
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) {
    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
    this.age=age;
    this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

    function getName() {
        return this.firstname;
    }
}

var myFather = new person("John","Doe",50,"blue");
document.write( myFather.getName() );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getName() {
    return this.firstname;
}
```

should be

```
this.getName = function () {
    return this.firstname;
}
```

And it's better to attach such method to the prototype of `person`.

```
person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.firstname;
}
```

Comment: can u explain it a bit why?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed it's a bit of a long story but this may help out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 0):

here is the code.

```
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) {
    this.getName =  function getName() {
        return firstname;
    }
}

document.write( (new person("John","Doe",50,"blue")).getName() );
</script>
```